# I18n_routing, empty path + nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a Rails website using the gem I18n_routing. I have a path such as this:

```
domain.com/<place>/bookings
```

where place could be "new-york". My goal is to get the routes translated like this:

```
domain.com/<place>/bokningar
```

I am trying to translate this through I18n_routing like so:

```
  resources :places, :path => '', :except => [:index, :create, :new] do

    #resources :flight_pages, :path => 'flyg', :only => [:show, :index]
    #resources :hotel_pages, :path => 'hotell', :only => [:show, :index]    
    localized do
      resources :bookings, :except => [:edit, :update] do
        get :get_method_desc, :on => :collection
        get :get_image_path, :on => :collection      
      end
    end  
    get :autocomplete_place_name, :on => :collection     
  end

  localized do
    resources :places, :only => [:index, :create, :new]
  end
```

with the translation file like this:

```
  resources: 
    places: 'plats'
    bookings: 'bokningar'
```

I run into a problem where if I have it like the above, I18n_routing does not recognize that "bookings" need to be translated.

If I change the setup to put localized do outside the whole resoure:

```
    localized do
  resources :places, :path => '', :except => [:index, :create, :new] do

    #resources :flight_pages, :path => 'flyg', :only => [:show, :index]
    #resources :hotel_pages, :path => 'hotell', :only => [:show, :index]    

      resources :bookings, :except => [:edit, :update] do
        get :get_method_desc, :on => :collection
        get :get_image_path, :on => :collection      
      end

    get :autocomplete_place_name, :on => :collection     
  end
    end
  localized do
    resources :places, :only => [:index, :create, :new]
  end
```

I get the empty path "places" translated so the route turns into:

```
domain.com/plats/<place>/bokningar
```

I tried to set `places: ""` in the translation file but then I18n_routing just skips it.

What should I do to get a translation like this:

```
domain.com/<place>/bokningar (:se)
domain.com/<place>/bookings (:en)
```

i.e. keeping the empty path and translated the nested resource "bookings"?

Edit in response to Aman Garg:
 Paths that I use for these are

```
new_place_booking_path(@place) #=> domain.com/<place>/bookings/new
place_bookings_path(@place) #=> domain.com/<place>/bookings
```

Comment: can you paste some example like how u r making path for mentioned url. I mean path u r using right now. Like some_link_path or static url ?

Comment: Sure, I have added some examples now. Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Have you specified `se:` in your translation file?

Comment: Does it work when you fire up console, set `I18n.locale = :se` and try some paths?

Comment: @Christoffer: have u tried the solution mentioned below in answer, i think its exactly stating the solution what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem for providing dynamic translated routes according to language. It will generate the url on the basis of locale just like I18n. There is easy implementation for this:

https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes

Follow steps mentioned in the documention on github. You can define translations for route in yml files. e.g: in config/locales/routes.yml

```
en:
  routes:
    # you can leave empty locales, for example the default one
se:
  routes:
    places: 'plats'
    bookings: 'bokningar'
```

Comment: I knew about rails-translate-routes but I never tried it. It works better than I18n_routing and it solved my problem. Thanks Aman!